# Error while copying set of files

Tags: c#, file

I want to copy set of image files from one path folder to another folder. But error occurred:

> Illegal characters in path

I have tried...

```
string pathImg = "C" + ":\\compaynameSupportFileImg";

if (!Directory.Exists(pathImg))
{
    DirectoryInfo di = Directory.CreateDirectory(pathImg);
    di.Attributes = FileAttributes.Directory | FileAttributes.Hidden;
    string[] jpgFilesNames = Directory.GetFiles(
       @"C:\Program Files (x86)\compayname\name", "*.jpg", SearchOption.AllDirectories);

    string targetDirectoryImg = pathImg + "\\*.jpg";
    foreach (var item in jpgFilesNames)
    {
        File.Copy(item, targetDirectoryImg, true);
    }
}
```

Comment: You can't have *.jpg in the target path. It should just be the directory you want the source files copied to.

Comment: @itsme86 Yes Sir I want to copy whole image.jpg files to anther folder. How can I ?

Comment: The *source* is *.jpg, the *target* is just a directory name.

Comment: @Duston Are you sure? [The documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/c6cfw35a(v=vs.110).aspx) says, that the second parameter for `File.Copy` must be a file name. It may not be a directory name ("…This cannot be a directory…").

Comment: Ah, right, that's copying a single file.  My bad also.  So what happens when you call File.Copy() and either item or tagetDirectoryImg have spaces but the strings themselves are not delimited by "" ?  In other words, what would happen if the source were "Hello" instead of what you have?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just use:

```
string pathImg = "C" + ":\\compaynameSupportFileImg";
if (!Directory.Exists(pathImg))
{
    DirectoryInfo di = Directory.CreateDirectory(pathImg);
    di.Attributes = FileAttributes.Directory | FileAttributes.Hidden;
    string[] jpgFilesNames = Directory.GetFiles(@"C:\Program Files (x86)\compayname\name", "*.jpg", SearchOption.AllDirectories);
    foreach (var item in jpgFilesNames)
    {
        File.Copy(item, Path.Combine(pathImg, Path.GetFileName(item)), true);
    }
}
```

You do not need `targetDirectoryImg` here. Because it will has value like `C:\compaynameSupportFileImg\*.jpg` and it isn't path to target folder

Comment: Are you sure? [The documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/c6cfw35a(v=vs.110).aspx) says, that the second parameter for `File.Copy` must be a file name. It may not be a directory name ("…This cannot be a directory…").

Comment: I have changed 'file' variable name to 'item'. Once again Thanks.

Comment: Yes, sorry, there should be 'file' )) Glad to have been of help